# Почему youtube_dl не скачивает видео в определенном формате?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

```
import pprint
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'format':'[height=720][filesize<20M]'
    }

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    a=ydl.extract_info('https://youtu.be/Ee7Wba4SfOw', download=1)
```

почему то видео с такими параметрами нету, хотя сам смотрел на список форматов и такой имеется. В чем проблема - в библиотеке?

Answer (score 0):

Видео скачивается если вместо знака равно '=' добавить знак меньше или равно '<=' в словаре
вот так:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format':'[height<=720][filesize<20M]'
    }
```

```
[youtube] Ee7Wba4SfOw: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Alfa Romeo 'Feel For Yourself' _ Unreal Engine 5 Cinematic-Ee7Wba4SfOw.mp4
[download] 100% of 4.17MiB in 01:39
```

Comment: Проблема не в том какой знак поставить, а то что есть видео с разрешением 720p и весит он ≈15MiB (что как раз подходит под требования)